# Editing phpci.yml File for my Project

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpcodesniffer, php-ci

I've installed PHPCI and have added a project named 'myproject' in PHPCI for testing. It is asked that I should include a 'phpci.yml' file in the root directory of the project. Here is how this 'phpci.tml' file should look like:

Click [here](https://github.com/Block8/PHPCI/wiki/Adding-PHPCI-Support-to-Your-Projects) to see the file pattern. Which part of this file should I edit to include it in my project as myproject's description as given below?

1. Project root direcotry: myproject
2. database name: mydb
3. database user: root
4. database pass: secret
5. host: localhost

Can some one please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create **phpci.yml** file in your project's root directory, in your case it will be **myproject/phpci.yml** . This file contains configuration and usage of plugins. You might also need those plugins in your project for PHP-CI to test build. Use composer to to include those plugins in your project. To do that add another file in your project's root directory **myproject/composer.json**.

This happens when PHP-CI cannot find a plugin from its own directory, then it uses project's vendor directory to execute those plugins.

#### Example File/Config Format:

Suppose you have directory structure like this:

- ./myproject/
- ./myproject/protected/
- ./myproject/assets/
- ./myproject/protected/runtime/

and you want to run PHP-CI on **./myproject/protected/** while looking to skip **./myproject/assets/** & **./myproject/protected/runtime/** directories then your **phpci.yml** will look like this:

#### phpci.yml

```
build_settings:
    ignore:
        - "assets"
        - "protected/runtime/"
setup:
    composer:
        action: "install"
test:
    php_parallel_lint:
        directory: "protected"
        ignore:
            - "assets"
            - "protected/runtime"
    php_code_sniffer:
        path: "protected"
        ignore:
            - "assets"
            - "protected/runtime"
        standard: "code-sniffer-settings.xml"
        allowed_errors: 10
        allowed_warnings: 10
    php_unit:
        config:
            - "protected/tests/phpunit.xml"
        args: "--stderr"
        path: "protected/tests/unit"
    php_cpd:
        allow_failures: true
        path: "protected"
        ignore:
            - "assets"
            - "protected/runtime"
    php_docblock_checker:
        allowed_warnings: -1
        path: "protected"
        ignore:
            - "assets"
            - "protected/runtime"
    php_loc:
        directory: "protected"
    pdepend:
        directory: "protected"
```

#### composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
        "sebastian/phpdcd": "*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
        "jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint": "0.*",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "2.0.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2"
    }
}
```

As to answer your question:

> Which part of this file should I edit to include it in my project

**Change test: section in phpci.yml and remove extra plugins that you don't want to be executed by PHP-CI, while leave composer section as it is, PHP-CI will run composer automatically on its own when testing a build.**

Comment: Thanks Waqar for your such informative answer. I've got it. Thanks for this help.
Now one more thing is that:
1. What if I want that my commits should get deployed automatically from my bit bucket repo to my staging server with PHP CI whenever I commit from my local repo?
2. and the build must get started automatically instead of I manually build each time?

Can you plz guide me in this regard or suggest some helpful docs or podcasts on this?

Comment: and what If I only want to deploy (not test the code) my commits automatically to from my bit bucket repo to my staging server?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, PHP-CI doesn't provide deployment functionality. It can run/test build if you commit anything in your git but it won't deploy. Check here https://github.com/Block8/PHPCI/wiki/Autobuilding-From-GitHub
 
More details to understand automatic deployment through git to any server look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps
You can also use Capistrano for build deployment http://capistranorb.com/